# Is RLock a sensible default over Lock?

Tags: python, multithreading

the threading module in Python provides two kinds of locks: A common lock and a reentrant lock. It seems to me, that if I need a lock, I should always prefer the RLock over the Lock; mainly to prevent deadlock situations.

Besides that, I see two points, when to prefer a Lock over a RLock:

- RLock has a more complicated internal structure and may therefore have worse performance.
- Due to some reason, I want to prevent a thread recursing through the lock.

Is my reasoning correct? Can you point out other aspects?

Comment: #2 is unlikely to be a good reason; the only case where it's not a guaranteed deadlock is if the recursion acquires non-blocking and has some reasonable course of action when it can't verify it holds the lock. And #1 doesn't apply on Python 3.2+. A legitimate reason to prefer `Lock` is when the lock must be released in a different thread than the one that acquired it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two points:

- In officially released Python versions (2.4, 2.5... up to 3.1), an RLock is much slower than a Lock, because Locks are implemented in C and RLocks in Python (this will change in 3.2)
- A Lock can be released from any thread (not necessarily the thread which acquire()d it), while an RLock has to be released by the same thread which acquired it

Bottom line, I'd suggest to only use an RLock if it matches the semantics you are looking for, otherwise stick to Locks by default.

Comment: That said, `RLock`s can simplify code. If there are two methods that both need to hold the lock, and one calls the other, architecting for plain `Lock` requires you to split the "inner" method into an unlocked utility, with the public name locking and calling the inner method, while the "outer" method calls the unlocked utility directly. And you need to do this every time you engage in code reuse of this form. In addition, `RLock` removes the risk of silently locking in one thread and unlocking in another (it enforces lock and unlock from the same thread); prevents errors in common case.

Comment: Given the performance hit in 3.1 and below, I could see generally recommending `Lock` there for practical reasons, but in 3.2+, `RLock` is less complicated to use, prevents common errors, and is just as efficient; you really use `Lock` only when you need `Lock` specific features (e.g. cross-thread acquire/release, using it as a barrier for waiters; waiter creates `Lock`, `acquire`s it once, adds to a list of wait locks, `acquire`s again, blocking; alerter then `release`s to let the `waiter` keep going (of course, I'm just describing what `Condition` does for you, so don't do this yourself).

Answer (score 4):

Normally you should structure your code such that you never need to recursively lock in normal operation (basically it forces you to use locks tightly around the protected datastructures they are are protecting). Therefore you want to catch an anomalous recursive locking.

Comment: Your answer implies that [the example](http://effbot.org/zone/thread-synchronization.htm#re-entrant-locks-rlock) used to motivate `RLock` in the first place should be re-written using tighter locks, at which point it won't need `RLock`. Would you agree? And if so, what is a good example that motivates the need for `RLock`?