# Why is my metaclass not behaving as expected

Tags: python, metaclass

Okay so Im starting to mess around with voodoo and the darker side of Python with metaclasses, I wanted to get a simple example working before I modified it further, why is it not printing the print statement when I execute this code,

```
class Versioned(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)

    def __setattr__(cls, key, value):
        print "Setting attr %s to %s" % (key, value)
        return object.__setattr__(cls, key, value)

class Test(object):
    __metaclass__ = Versioned

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2

a = Test()
a.b = 31
print dir(a)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing to understand is that a metaclass is not a *class* per se--it is a *callable that returns a class*--a *class factory*. It serves the same purpose as [`type(__name__, __bases__, __dict__)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type).

```
>>> type('myclass', (), {})
<class '__main__.myclass'>
```

When you define `__metaclass__`, you are merely [`overriding the default class factory for that specific class or module`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#__metaclass__). For example, this is a metaclass:

```
def setattr_logging_class(name, bases, dict_):
    """I am a metaclass"""
    def __setattr__(self, k, v):
        print "{} set attribute {} to {}".format(self, k, v)
        super(self.__class__, self).__setattr__(k, v)
    dict_['__setattr__'] = __setattr__
    cls = type(name, bases, dict_)
    return cls

class MyClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = setattr_logging_class
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1

obj = MyClass()
obj.b = 2

print obj.__dict__
```

**Most importantly, a metaclass does not participate in the method resolution of the created class** (unless you change `bases`). This is why your `Versioned.__setattr__` is not visible to your `Test` instances. All `Versioned` did was return a new class (of type `Versioned` rather than type `type`) with the same `name`, `bases` and `dict_` the Python runtime parsed out of your `class Test(object):` block.

Classes are themselves callable (via their [`__new__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) method). (`__new__` is for classes what `__call__` is for instances.)

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __new__(cls_self, *args, **kwargs):
        print "I am {} called with {} and {}".format(cls_self, args, kwargs)
        return None

myobj = MyClass(1,2,3,a=4,b=5,c=6)
print myobj # == None
```

Since classes are callable, you can use a class as a metaclass. In fact, `type` is a class. Although, *you can just as well use an instance with a `__call__` method!*  These two examples are similar and there isn't anything you may want to do that can't be done in either way. (In fact, using an object is usually more straightforward.)

```
class MetaClass(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dict_):
        print "I am {} called with {}, {}, {}".format(cls, name, bases, dict_)
        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, dict_)

class MetaObject(object):
    def __call__(self, name, bases, dict_):
        print "I am {} called with {}, {}, {}".format(self, name, bases, dict_)
        return type(name, bases, dict_)


class MyClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = MetaClass


class MyClass2(object):
    __metaclass__ = MetaObject()
```

Note that Python has many other metaprogramming methods besides metaclasses. In particular, Python >= 2.6 added support for class decorators, which covers most of the use cases for metaclasses with a much simpler interface. (Rather than create the class yourself, you get an already-created class object you modify.)

You can see a survey of multiple metaprogramming methods at [this stackoverflow answer I recently wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13610654/how-to-make-built-in-containers-sets-dicts-lists-thread-safe/13618333#13618333). The original question was "How do I make a built-in Python container type threadsafe?"

Comment: With a last name like 'Avila', how could you possibly have gone to school with the _Dominicans_? A true open mind you must have...

Answer (score 1):

I never really used metaclasses, but I think you're mixing inheritance with metaclasses. Metaclasses are there to build instances, but they don't add anything implicitly to your instance. There is no reason that the `__setattr__` method should be imported in `Test`. To add it explicitely, you need to modify the `Test` dict (`dct`). Something like `dct["__setattr__"] = cls.__setattr__`. However, it does not work, and I don't understand why. The only way I found to make it work was :

```
class Versioned(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        print("BLAH")
        def __setattr__(cls, key, value):
            print("Setting attr %s to %s" % (key, value))
            return object.__setattr__(cls, key, value)
        dct["__setattr__"] = __setattr__
        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)
```

I hope this can help :-)

Finally, this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python) can help you understand metaclasses in python.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining `__setattr__` for the class itself, not for its instances. This will result in the print statement executing:

```
Test.key = value
```