# Can I insert a line into ruamel.yaml's CommentedMap?

Tags: python, yaml, ordereddictionary, ruamel.yaml

I understand that this is related to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16664874/how-can-i-add-the-element-at-the-top-of-ordereddict-in-python?lq=1), but what I'm mostly concerned about is whether this might mess with things such as the preserved comments.

```
import ruamel.yaml as yaml

yaml_str = """\
first_name: Art
occupation: Architect  # This is an occupation comment
about: Art Vandelay is a fictional character that George invents...
"""

data = yaml.load(yaml_str, Loader=yaml.RoundTripLoader)

# I'd like to extend CommentedMap so that I can do something like:
data.insert(1, 'last_name', 'Vandelay')

print(yaml.dump(data, Dumper=yaml.RoundTripDumper))
```

Should output:

```
first_name: Art
last_name: Vandelay
occupation: Architect  # This is an occupation comment
about: Art Vandelay is a fictional character that George invents...
```

Should **not** output:

```
first_name: Art
last_name: Vandelay    # This is an occupation comment
occupation: Architect
about: Art Vandelay is a fictional character that George invents...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Python 2.7, and on Python 3.X with at least ruamel.yaml 0.11.11, this works fine:

```
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
first_name: Art
occupation: Architect  # This is an occupation comment
about: Art Vandelay is a fictional character that George invents...
"""

data = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(yaml_str)
data.insert(1, 'last name', 'Vandelay')

print(ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(data))
```

gives:

```
first_name: Art
last name: Vandelay
occupation: Architect  # This is an occupation comment
about: Art Vandelay is a fictional character that George invents...
```

as the end-of-line comments are associated with the key of the line in the `CommentedMap`.  (Python 2.7.11 on Linux Mint with ruamel.yaml 0.11.10.)

This will not work on older versions of ruamel.yaml with Python3 as the `.insert()` you are using is a feature of the full-fledged `ruamel.ordereddict` and the OrderedDict in the standard library doesn't have that method. Therefore you need to graft an `.insert()` function onto the `CommentedMap`:

```
import ruamel.yaml
from ruamel.yaml.comments import CommentedMap
from ruamel.yaml.compat import ordereddict

yaml_str = """\
first_name: Art
occupation: Architect  # This is an occupation comment
about: Art Vandelay is a fictional character that George invents...
"""

def com_insert(self, pos, key, value, comment=None):
    od = ordereddict()
    od.update(self)
    for k in od:
        del self[k]
    for index, old_key in enumerate(od):
        if pos == index:
            self[key] = value
        self[old_key] = od[old_key]
    if comment is not None:
        self.yaml_add_eol_comment(comment, key=key)

CommentedMap.insert = com_insert

data = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(yaml_str)
data.insert(1, 'last name', 'Vandelay', comment="new key")

print(ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(data))
```

gives on Python3:

```
first_name: Art
last name: Vandelay    # new key
occupation: Architect  # This is an occupation comment
about: Art Vandelay is a fictional character that George invents...
```

Please note that there is an optional parameter for `insert()` that allows you to specify a comment for the newly inserted key-value pair. The above works because deleting a key from a `CommentedMap` doesn't remove the comment associated with the key. So I temporarily park the old key-value pairs in `od`
delete all key-values, and then copy them back inserting the new stuff at the right moment

The above `insert`, with comment, has been added in ruamel.yaml 0.11.11 for
both Python 2 and 3

---

The `.round_trip_load()` is equivalent to `.load(...., Loader=ruamel.yaml.RoundTripLoader, ...)` and `.round_trip_dump()` to `.dump(....., Dumper=ruamel.yaml.RoundTripDumper, allow_unicode=True, ...)

Comment: wait what?? I had no idea ruamel.ordereddict had `.insert()` :D

Comment: That is excusable, the author of that package is notoriously lazy when it comes to writing accessible documentation.

Comment: I'm just happy that it's available at all. Thank you! But can I somehow use `ruamel.ordereddict` even though I'm using `Python 3`?

Comment: Looking at [compat.py, line 12](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/yaml/src/dd14fefad83336b46af54902d781387776b22789/compat.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#compat.py-12) it seems all I have to do is `pip install ruamel.ordereddict`. Is this a correct analysis?

Comment: Unfortunately not. `ruamel.ordereddict` only works on Python2. I got most of it working on 3.2 (after that there were rather big changes in the C `dict` source that I tried to follow as close as possible). But then found that for 3.5 a C based OrderedDict was being done *from scratch* and decided not to spent more time on that and focus on other things.

Comment: So what you would need to do is create a new CommentedMap, copy the key, value pairs over *with any comments* and insert the new key at the right moment. I can look at extending the answer with that tomorrow.

Comment: Yeah, if you have the time, that would be super helpful! Thanks!

Comment: This is now in ruamel.yaml 0.11.11 and [documented](http://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example.html). Thanks for the inspiration.

Comment: What I created with this is a [hook](https://gist.github.com/demux/39594b46b18fa6f76c7d63f5c3ccb762) for [Python Schematics](https://schematics.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) The goal is to reformat the yaml as little as possible when saving back but to also have a basic structure for the data when new data is added.