# Thread safety of python class members through "__setaddr__" and "__getattribute__" locking

Tags: python, multithreading, oop, locking, python-multithreading

I'm considering using the following design pattern:

```py
from threading import Lock

class FieldsLocker:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lock = Lock()

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name == 'lock':
            return super().__setattr__(name, value)
        with self.lock:
            print('locked set', name, '=', value)
            return super().__setattr__(name, value)

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name == 'lock':
            return super().__getattribute__(name)
        with self.lock:
            print('locked get', name)
            return super().__getattribute__(name)

class MyClass(FieldsLocker):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2

o = MyClass()
o.a = o.b
```

It seems to lock class members whenever they're set and get, it produces the following output:

> locked set a = 1
> locked set b = 2
> locked get b
> locked set a = 2

I have 2 questions:

**1. Is there any risk of using `__setattr__` and `__getattribute__` methods for ensuring thread safety of class members in general?**

Aside of the fact that a single lock is used for all fields (which is possibly less efficient than using few individual locks for specific members where strictly necessary).

**2. Is there any risk of using reusable `FieldsLocker` parent class from example above?**

Aside of the fact that:

- MyClass may break it by declaring its own `self.lock = None`
- the user may forget to put `super().__init_()` and may want to override `__setattr__` and `__getattribute__` themselves (and may forget or intentionally not call super() equivalents of these methods).

Comment: Side question: is there even a point to use a lock when getting items?

Comment: I think you would find the answers to the question [How to make built-in containers (sets, dicts, lists) thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13610654/how-to-make-built-in-containers-sets-dicts-lists-thread-safe) useful.

Comment: To answer your side question: Generally speaking, yes.